# How Can Set Icon for each node by c# Ajax Response in Jstree?

Tags: ajax, jstree

How Can Set Icon for each node by c# Ajax Response in Jstree? 
in this line see Ajax jstree :
[Webmethod is not fired by jsTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28242418/webmethod-is-not-fired-by-jstree/31771306#31771306)
the ajax jstree successfully run, but how can show Icon for each node ?
in this line :
_GG_JSTree.icons = "";   How Can set icons?

```
 private static List<GG_JSTree> AddChildNodes(int _ParentID, int NumOfChildren, string ParentName)
{
    List<GG_JSTree> GG_JSTreeArray = new List<GG_JSTree>();
    int n = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < NumOfChildren; i++)
    {
        int CurrChildId = (_ParentID == 0) ? n : ((_ParentID * 10) + i);
        GG_JSTree _GG_JSTree = new GG_JSTree();
        _GG_JSTree.data = (_ParentID == 0) ? "root" + "-Child" + i.ToString() : ParentName + CurrChildId.ToString() + i.ToString();
        _GG_JSTree.state = "closed";  //For async to work
        _GG_JSTree.icons = "";   How Can set?
        _GG_JSTree.IdServerUse = (int)CurrChildId;
        _GG_JSTree.children = null;
        _GG_JSTree.attr = new GG_JSTreeAttribute { id = CurrChildId.ToString(), selected = false };
        GG_JSTreeArray.Add(_GG_JSTree);
        n = n + 10;
    }

    return GG_JSTreeArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the format spec:
https://github.com/vakata/jstree#the-required-json-format

- The property name is `icon`, not `icons`.
  ( `state` should be an object, no a string, etc.

As for the `icon` property it is explained in the above link:

> `icon` - a string which will be used for the node's icon - this can either be a path to a file, or a className (or list of classNames), which you can style in your CSS (font icons also work).

Basically - just take a deeper look at the docs and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
_GG_JSTree.icon = "glyphicon glyphicon-heart";
```

if u use bootstrap to show heart icon

'icon' defined in 'Type' plugin section may override this.